# Changing the font colour of one item in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

The title pretty much says it all. I've got a ListView I'm using in my navigation bar/side menu and want to change the colour of the first item. I can't seem to get a hold of the view itself to setTextColor() or whatever the method would be, so how else can I do this?

Comment: could you post the `getView()` method in your custom ArrayAdapter (assuming you are using a custom one).

Comment: Going by roflharrison's answer, I added

    if(position == 0)
            txtTitle.setTextColor(0xFFAEA47B);

to it, where txtTitle was the textview in question

Comment: Yes - that would be what you would want to do in the `getView()` method of your custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the colour of the textview (or whatever view) in your [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) by overriding or implementing [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)).

I assume you don't have a custom adapter or you wouldn't be asking this question, so you might want to check out some tutorials on how to use a custom adapter to create a custom appearance for your list items.